# View become null after inject constructor presenter with dagger 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, android-mvp

Hello I'm new with dagger 2. when I run code below, I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ali.daggerplayground/com.ali.daggerplayground.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

When I'm not use dagger, this code run fine. I don't understand what make the view become null. maybe someone can give me explanation about this?

this my Activity.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), MainContract.View {

@Inject
internal lateinit var mPresenter: MainContract.Presenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    App.main.inject(this)
    tv.text = "This Button"
    mPresenter.attach(this)
    mPresenter.getImage()
}

override fun onSuccess(message: String?) {
    Log.i("MessageReturn", message)
    tv.text = message
}
```

this my presenter:

```
class MainPresenter @Inject constructor(private val mView: MainContract.View) :
    MainContract.Presenter {

override fun attach(view: MainContract.View) {

}

override fun getImage() {
    mView.onSuccess("success")
}
```

this is my module:

```
@Module
class ModuleMain {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMainPresenter(mainView: MainContract.View): MainContract.Presenter {
    return MainPresenter(mainView)
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMainView(): MainContract.View {
    return MainActivity()
}
```

this component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ModuleMain::class, ModuleNetwork::class])
interface ComponentMain {

fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder

    fun moduleNetwork(moduleNetwork: ModuleNetwork): Builder
    fun build(): ComponentMain
}
```

Comment: why is your `MainPresenter` a singleton and `MainView` not?

Comment: I just add @Singleton, but still crash.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, your `ModuleMain` is not correct because you should not provide your view in that module, change it like this

```
@Module
class ModuleMain {

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideMainPresenter(): MainContract.Presenter {
    return MainPresenter()
  }
}
```

And of course, `MainPresenter` should look like this

```
class MainPresenter @Inject constructor() :
    MainContract.Presenter {

  override fun attach(view: MainContract.View) {
    mView = view
  }
}
```

Comment: can't I just inject use constructor?

Comment: No you should not because you can't create an Activity like this `MainActivity()`, an activity needs to be created through `Intent` and such

Comment: That's why you see in your `Activity`, you have this line to set view `mPresenter.attach(this)`

Comment: is there away to not use presenter.attach()?

Comment: No, that's the standard MVP with Dagger2

Comment: If you would inject the MainView in MainPresenter and MainPresenter in MainView. It will be cyclic graph and dagger doesn't do that. DAG-> Directed Acyclic Graph